# Mongoose returns undefined for an existing field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

After a mongoose request I have my document `doc` which is the result of the query

Here is the schema used

```
var searchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    original : String,
    images : [String],
    image: String
});
```

The model :

```
var searchModel = mongoose.model('Search', searchSchema);
```

Code used:

```
searchModel.findOne({original : input}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    if (typeof doc !== "undefined") {
        console.log(doc);
                    console.log(doc.image);
    }
});
```

The first `console.log`:

```
{ 
    _id: 531401bf714420359fd929c9,
    image: 'http://url.com/image.jpg',
    original: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' 
}
```

The second returns `undefined`, but the previous one does show an existing `image` property, which means that it exists.

My schema doesn't have anything special so I don't understand what may be happening here..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll see this when you haven't added the field to your schema.

Add `image` to your schema and it should work:

```
image: String
```

Comment: It already is. I tried deleting all my documents, changing the field name and checking to be sure it is in the schema, then re adding everything, and while the property is there (and I can even select it in my queries) it is undefined when I try to access it, strangely

Comment: @Malharhak Can you update your question to include the code that defines the schema and model and performs the query that creates `doc`?

Comment: Ok never mind I have a versioning bug so my schema didn't have the right property.

Comment: I could kiss you (but I wont :) )!

Answer (score 0):

This is do to the fact that the toString() method of the object returns the _doc property. You can use:
console.log(doc._doc.image);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but accessing the property like this `doc[0].image` works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the bracket notation like that:

```
doc['image']
```

If it works, I'm not able to explain you why, but maybe someone could shed some light on this?

Comment: Yes I did try that but it didn't change anything

Comment: Can you provide the query you're doing?

Comment: I added informations about the schema/model/query in the question

Comment: doc.image and doc['image'] is the same thing. please see my answer explaining why this happens.